# Lightning Web Component: how can I use Get Child Records UI API?

Tags: lightning-web-components

According to documentation, [Lightning Data Services is built on top of UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api).
So my question is: How I do to user [Get Child Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_features_records_child_relationships.htm) UI API?

Comment: Nothing. I just created an Apex AuraEnabled method to return the records and wire up on the frontend with `wire` function

Comment: I was expecting to have something similar to `import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';` (with the name likely to `getChildRecord`) so bringing child records into component with something like `@wire(getChildRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the answer to this is coming to us in Spring 22 in the form of lightning/uiRelatedListApi (**important to note - this will be in beta**).

From the [Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_modules.htm&type=5&release=236):

> This module includes new wire adapters to get records, metadata, and record count for a related list.
>
> - getRelatedListRecords—Returns record data for a related list.
> - getRelatedListInfo—Returns metadata for a related list.
> - getRelatedListsInfo—Returns metadata for multiple related lists.
> - getRelatedListCount—Returns the record count for a related list.

The example code they provide:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';

export default class LdsGetRelatedListRecords extends LightningElement {
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
parentRecordId: '001RM000003UNu6YAG',
relatedListId: 'Contacts',
fields: ['Contact.Name','Contact.Id']
})
}
```

Keep in mind because this will be a Beta feature, it may not make it to general availability, so I wouldn't start putting it in production code in the event they axe this.  Hopefully not though because this'll be a really useful feature.

EDIT: Still in beta but the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_get_related_list_records) is now available.  This is the example code included:

```
// wireGetRelatedListRecords.js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
export default class WireGetRelatedListRecords extends LightningElement {
    error;
    records;
    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '001RM000003UNu6YAG',
        relatedListId: 'Contacts',
        fields: ['Contact.Id','Contact.Name']
    })listInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.records = data.records;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.records = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The example code here doesnt even work (it doesnt wire the record to any actual variable or function) and hopefully the docs will come for this but in the meantime there appears to be more parameters than listed anyway - it seems similar to the api here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_related_list_records.htm

Comment: @ChrisAbraham Hopefully they clean it up soon.  They have a link to documentation for the new module but because it's not the current release the link's broken at the moment.  Once that's working I'll likely be able to update my answer with more info.

Comment: @ChrisAbraham, this blog post has working code that addresses your concerns: https://www.infallibletechie.com/2022/02/how-to-display-related-records-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to do this using the [`getRecordUi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui) wire adapter and specifying a `childRelationships` parameter:

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecordUi } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getRecordUi, { recordIds: '123', childRelationships: "Account.Opportunities" })
  myRecord;
}
```

*Note that layoutTypes and modes are still required*

Comment: This seems to be one of the biggest myths about this feature! **childRelationships** is **not** an attribute of **getRecordUi**! I don't know why everybody is referencing it from each other! Copy pasting it from others does not make it true. It does actually **not** have **any effect** on the result of getRecordUi.

Comment: Agree... Important feature missing here